# "Downside" versus "drawback"

Tags: word-usage, difference

My essay was about the advantages and disadvantages of international travel between countries.

When it comes to the disadvantages, I wrote *downside* to avoid repeating *disadvantage*, but my teacher suggested to use *drawback* instead. She said *downside* was not appropriate.

Can you tell me the difference, and when to use both of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Downside* is more modern/informal, and a bit slangy (some would still call it "business jargon").

Interestingly, people sometimes head up the section on, say, a business case assessment, with singular *Downside* - followed by perhaps several separate disadvantages. They usually head it up with plural *Downsides* though. But it would be very unusual to use *Drawback* or *Disadvantage* in the singular there.

*Drawbacks* is somewhat more informal than *disadvantages*, but they're both fine for almost all contexts.